# Is it possible to include category slugs in the entry URL format?

Tags: entry, url, format, tag

Is it possible to include category or tag slug in the entry URL format?
Would you please let me know the tags that make it, if possible?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want the first category that's selected in the field, you'd set your "Entry URL Format" setting to:

```
{categoryFieldHandle.first().slug}
```

You can access any of your custom fields by their handle in a similar way.

Comment: Just in case there is no first categoryFieldHandle, I use `{categoryFieldHandle.first().slug ?? 'no-category'}`